# Twilio Conversation: Handling of old messages when a new conversation is created out of Closed Conversation

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

In twilio conversation documentation, it says-

```
If new message comes into closed Conversation, a new Conversation will be auto-created with 
the Participant who initiated the Conversation. At this point, there is no automatic addition
 of other Participants, so you should add them to the newly created Conversation.
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/states-timers#closed-conversations

In this case what happens to the old messages, do they get copied to the new conversation. If not, what is the recommended way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

A new conversation will not get the messages from the old closed conversation. If you do want to add the messages to that conversation, then you'd need to [fetch them from the API and create new messages using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-message-resource).